# Which programming patterns would be appropriate for a ‘sea battle’-type game?

Tags: design-patterns

I want to improve knowledge of different programming patterns. 
I want to write a simple game. Which pattern would you suggest for a simple/casual game?

edit: The game will be a "sea battle" type game, with simple AI and maybe later i'll add some networking to it.

Comment: I would recommend the "game engine" pattern.

Comment: I like a nice plaid pattern personally, though that probably just reflects my Keltic ancestry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to describe the game in a bit more detail to get useful suggestions for what patterns to use.

A lot of the examples in the gang of four [Design Patters](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Design-patterns-elements-reusable-object-oriented/dp/0201633612/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1282589981&sr=8-1) book use a game to illustrate the pattern at hand.

Comment: the information about what you can expect: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns_(book)

Answer (score 0):

There are many patterns that would be appropriate for a game.  (I would say "all of them" but I'm trying to break the idea that those listed in the gang of four Design Patters book are the only design patterns).

A better question would be "What game would you suggest to use patterns on?"